# How to undo a git rm after commit

Tags: git

I have a file name `file.txt`.

I have made some changes in the `file.txt`.

I commit and push these changes.

But now I realize that I don't need any change in the file in the current branch. So mistakenly I have done `git rm file.txt`. And then commit and pushed these deletion changes. But it is showing removed this file on my branch.

All I want is that I don't want to see any change in the `file.txt` in my branch.

Could anyone please help me here? I have searched on StackOverflow a lot. There are many answers but could not find my case.

Comment: I think what you want is just adding the file to .gitignore

Comment: No No, That file is in the master branch so I can not .gitignore. I just don't want any diff in my branch.

Comment: Revert the deletion, and add the file to `.gitignore`. If that's not what you meant, can you please elaborate more?

Comment: I want no diff of file.txt in my branch. That file.txt in the master branch as well. And I am in a seperate branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally, I got the answers that I want. Here is the steps that I followed.

```
git checkout deletion_commit_id^ -- file.txt
```

This will reverted the deletion and then `add`, `commit` and `push`.

After that, I have done undoing of all the changes of this file.

```
git checkout origin/master file.txt.
```

And then `add`, `commit` and `push`.

Comment: Using git version 2.38.1, `git checkout` fails with the `--` flag. I needed only to specify the path and filename relative to the cwd: `git checkout <yourcommithash>^ <path/filename.ext>`

Answer (score 0):

```
git reset HEAD
```

Should do it. If you don't have any uncommitted changes that you care about, then

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

should forcibly reset everything to your last commit. If you do have uncommitted changes, but the first command doesn't work, then save your uncommitted changes with git stash:

```
git stash
git reset --hard HEAD
git stash pop
```